# Issue in specify type for object in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have an set of data for which I need to specify type in typescript (type any is not recommended).
`'xyzzy': (2) [Array(4), 1],`

I get error when i specify its type as object. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

Comment: Is it nessesarily for object keys to be a strings?

Comment: For my data, i am getting key as string (the label and color)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify new type with `type` keyword;

```js
type MyType = {
  xyzzy: [number[], number],
  abs: [number[], number]
}
```

And then use this declaration

```js
const something: MyType = {
  xyzzy: [[0, 1, 2, 3], 1],
  abs: [[0, 1, 2, 3], 0],
}
```

Comment: How can i specify the value or write exactly, if i am getting data object as props from other component. Currently i am specifying it in my interface like : interface legendProps {
 
    data: any
}      i need to get ride of any here

Comment: Also can anybody tell me what will be type of this: let labelFormat: any = d3.format(".01f");  Now i have given any (which is not recommended)